# Unable to install EGit Task focused interface in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, egit, mylyn

I'm trying to install the latest **EGit 4.0.1** in Eclipse Luna but when I select the **Task focused interface** component I get this error:

[image]

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider - Task focused interface 4.0.1.201506240215-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 4.0.1.201506240215-r)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse Git Team Provider - Task focused interface 4.0.1.201506240215-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 4.0.1.201506240215-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not be found
```

I found several posts about the same problem and the answer is always the same, do not select that component, I know it is optional, but in this case I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Install mylyn and mylyn git connector as well

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you go into the Help -> Install page that you select the 'Contact all sites' checkbox, and that you have the Luna (or Mylyn) update sites in your available software sites - then it will automatically install the Mylyn connector, which is a necessary pre-requisite for the thing you are installing.